# How do I preserve directory structure when compiling CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am new to Coffeescript and I wonder where I should put them.

Eg. I have my app folder:

```
app/app.js
tests/unit/all.js
etc
```

When I use the "coffee" runner on node.js to watch my files in the root folder it will generate js files to a folder I specify eg. js.

So if the folder to be watched is looking like this:

```
app/app.coffee
tests/unit/all.coffee
etc
```

JS files will be generated to:

```
js/app.js
js/all.js
etc
```

As you can see I lose my js folder hierarchy.

How are you supposed to retain your original folder hierarchy?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe you want

```
coffee -cwo js .
```

That will compile `app/foo.coffee` to `js/app/foo.js`, and `test/bar.coffee` to `js/test/bar.js`.

As long as you stick to passing folder names to the `coffee` command, rather than individual file names, directory structure will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

It's not advised to do recursive watches, but for discussion on look here: 
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/932

Comment: To the contrary, it's perfectly advisable in cases like this.